# Installed Kippo on a remote machine, cant get the root access back

Tags: honeypot

This seems to be a foolish question, so I recently tried to install Kippo to my server (DigitalOcean).

I logged in to the server using PuTTY, configure the honeypot etc until it's working. Then the connection suddenly closed.

So every time is SSHd to the server, it will give me the honeypot. I cannot go to my original machine anymore. I cannot stop the Kippo service.

The only thing came to mind is to rebuild the server. Is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DO out-of-band console to sign into your server and disable kippo. Then, before restarting it, ensure your real sshd is listening on a alternate port and that you're able to connect.